# Custom Antd DatePicker Form Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, datepicker, antd

I am trying to write a custom Antd DatePicker component that will be used in an EditableTable cell, similar to the example shown [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell). According to the [Form docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls), custom form controls are given a controlled property `value` and an event `onChange`. However, I'm having some difficulty programmatically updating the Antd `form` instance with the values coming from the DatePicker component. For what it's worth, the custom Input component (`InputCell`) seems to be working properly.

```
const EditableContext = React.createContext(null);

const EditableRow = ({ index, ...props }) => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    return (
        <Form form={form} component={false}>
            <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
                <tr {...props} />
            </EditableContext.Provider>
        </Form>
    );
};

const InputCell = ({
    value,
    onChange,
    editing,
    toggleEdit,
    handleSave,
    record,
}) => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const form = useContext(EditableContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (editing) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
    }, [editing]);

    const toggle = () => {
        toggleEdit();
    };

    const handleChange = (value) => {
        if (onChange) {
            onChange(value);
        }
    };

    const save = async () => {
        try {
            const values = await form.validateFields();
            toggle();
            handleSave({ ...record }, { ...values });
        } catch (errInfo) {
            console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Input
            value={value}
            ref={inputRef}
            onPressEnter={save}
            onBlur={save}
            onChange={handleChange}
        />
    );
};

const DatePickerCell = ({
    value,
    onChange,
    toggleEdit,
    handleSave,
    record,
}) => {
    const form = useContext(EditableContext);
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    const toggle = () => {
        setVisible(!visible);
        toggleEdit();
    };

    const handleChange = async (value) => {
        if (onChange) {
            try {
                onChange(value);
                const values = await form.validateFields();
                toggle();
                handleSave({ ...record }, { ...values });
            } catch (errInfo) {
                console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <DatePicker
            value={moment(value)}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onOpenChange={toggle}
            open={visible}
            placeholder={moment(value)}
            format='YYYY-MM-DD'
        />
    );
};

const EditableCell = ({
    title,
    dataIndex,
    record,
    handleSave,
    editable,
    children,
    editableType,
    textAlign,
    ...restProps
}) => {
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const form = useContext(EditableContext);

    const toggleEdit = () => {
        setEditing(!editing);
        form.setFieldsValue({
            [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex],
        });
    };

    const editableComponent = (editableType) => {
        switch (editableType) {
            case 'date':
                return (
                    <DatePickerCell
                        toggleEdit={toggleEdit}
                        record={record}
                        handleSave={handleSave}
                        style={{
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            border: 'none',
                            borderRadius: '0px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                        }}
                        dataIndex={dataIndex}
                        format='YYYY-MM-DD'
                    />
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <InputCell
                        toggleEdit={toggleEdit}
                        record={record}
                        handleSave={handleSave}
                        editing={editing}
                    />
                );
        }
    };

    let childNode = children;

    if (editable) {
        childNode = editing ? (
            <Form.Item
                style={{
                    margin: 0,
                }}
                name={dataIndex}
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: `${title} is required.`,
                    },
                ]}
            >
                {editableComponent(editableType)}
            </Form.Item>
        ) : (
            <div className='editable-cell-value-wrap' onClick={toggleEdit}>
                {children}
            </div>
        );
    }

    return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
};
```

In the `handleChange` function of `DatePickerCell`, `values` always returns the initial value of the DatePicker, regardless of the value the user chooses. This leads me to believe there is an issue with the `form` instance not being updated properly (via `setFieldsValue`). Has anyone had experience with writing a custom DatePicker to be used in an Antd Form/is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious about this question, can you post your reproduce code on codesanbox?